# Convert Format in array of type Date to different Date format?

Tags: java, date, format

I have the following:

```
String[] string_dates = new String[10]
// read in strings formatted via fmt1 dd-MMM-yy)

Date[] date_dates = new Date[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    date_dates[i] = fmt1.parse(string_dates[i]);
```

What would be the most efficient way to format the Dates in date_dates[] to format dd-MM-yyyy? Should I convert the Strings in strings_dates[] to format dd-MM-yyyy first, and then read them into dates? Thank you.

Comment: A Date is a Date is a Date.  It's string representation is a completelhy different thing.  You can represent the *SAME* date in as many different formats as you wish.  Or read from any string format you want. Q:  So what exactly is your question?  How to *anticipate* what format you should use to read?

Comment: What I'm planning to do is put those dates in a symbol table. My program will prompt for a user inputted date of format dd-MM-yyyy, and then I was to be able to query the symbol take with the date key and spit out a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Date` is the representation of the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.  It has no concept of a format of it's own (other then that created by `toString`, which should not worry about)...

Once you have converted the `String` representation of the date to a `Date`, you should then use an appropriate formatter to format that date in what ever format you want...

```
String[] stringDates = {
    "01-MAR-2013",
    "02-MAR-2013",
    "03-MAR-2013",
    "04-MAR-2013",
    "05-MAR-2013",
    "06-MAR-2013",
    "07-MAR-2013",
    "08-MAR-2013",
    "09-MAR-2013",
    "10-MAR-2013"};

SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
Date[] dates = new Date[stringDates.length];
for (int i = 0; i < stringDates.length; i++) {
    try {
        dates[i] = inFormat.parse(stringDates[i]);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
for (Date date : dates) {
    System.out.println("[" + date + "] - [" + outFormat.format(date) + "]");
}
```

Which produces...

```
[Fri Mar 01 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [01-03-2013]
[Sat Mar 02 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [02-03-2013]
[Sun Mar 03 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [03-03-2013]
[Mon Mar 04 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [04-03-2013]
[Tue Mar 05 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [05-03-2013]
[Wed Mar 06 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [06-03-2013]
[Thu Mar 07 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [07-03-2013]
[Fri Mar 08 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [08-03-2013]
[Sat Mar 09 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [09-03-2013]
[Sun Mar 10 00:00:00 EST 2013] - [10-03-2013]
```

You should avoid the temptation to save the formatted `Date` and instead simply keep the `Date` object and format it as you need.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. If I want dates stored in my array of Dates to be formatted dd-MM-yyyy, rather than just print them out that way, would I then have to store the outFormat strings into another string array and then parse them back into a Date array with my target format?

Comment: No.  As I said, I would maintain the array of `Date`s and format them as required.  `Date` has much more functionality than `String`, it's also easier to format a `Date` than having to worry about trying to parse it back every time you want to change the format...

Answer (score 2):

you can format the string in to date type using following SimpledateFormat in java. Following is the example

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
String dateInString = "7-Jun-2013";

  try {

    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note**
For complete date and time patterns, please refer to this [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) JavaDoc.

Well in you case please take a look at these resources[click here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.htm)

You can give "dd-MM-yyy". Please try it

Comment: If I wanted the date to be formatted dd-MM-yyy rather than dd-MMM-yyyy in your example, how would I do that?

Comment: @corneria Change the format specifier in `SimpleDateFormat` to meet your needs

Comment: @corneria: Well what did you try? Given that the answer contains the string "dd-MMM-yyyy" did you try changing that to "dd-MM-yyyy"? Did you read through the code and try to understand what it was doing, looking up the documentation for any calls you didn't understand? It's important to use Stack Overflow only as a resource when your own efforts fail you - not as an alternative to putting in effort yourself.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: When trying to parse a date string of format dd-MMM-yyyy with a different format, it throws an unparceable date exception. Apologies for asking the question, but I've been working at this program for a long time and have searched through a lot of documentation.

Comment: @corneria: So separate out *parsing* from *formatting* - parse with one `SimpleDateFormat`, and format with another. This answer happens to use the same `SimpleDateFormat` for both, but I wouldn't have thought it was *that* hard to work out how to use different formatters.